# How to handle clients status in Phoenix Channel

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I've just followed Phoenix Channel and Presence Documentation from their official site. Things work fine as it's described.

As Channel documentation, it has join callback so I can handle something when client joins specific topic. But **why there's no leave callback** what I think it should be exist?

I've googled some and found I could use Presence to track client status. It worked either but I don't need inform it to clients actually. If I tried to catch presence_diff event in handle_out callback of Channel, it was called multiple times as number of clients.

As Presence documentation says...

> In case you want to use only a subset of the functionality provided by
>   Phoenix.Presence, such as tracking processes but without broadcasting
>   updates, we recommend that you look at the Phoenix.Tracker
>   functionality from the phoenix_pubsub project

But, Phoenix.Tracker requires :pubsub_server property initially.

Here're my questions again.

1. Why Phoenix.Channel does not implement leave-like callback.
2. How Can I handle client status(join/leave) for specific topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do get messages when client leaves the channel.

From the documentation for https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#module-terminate

Is there any reason this is not enough?

Comment: Thanks, I thought it's just about channel itself not client connection.